# OpenX vs. BittAds

Tags: openx

I Have tried both of them online (created online account). BittAds seemed a bit glitchy but anyway - which is better in your opinion and why? Maybe there are better solutions? I don't have a huge website...

Answer (score 0):

Google search results suggest that OpenX is much more popular with results in all advantages that an popular open source project has (updates, support, etc).